# cyrus-imapd is not work with sasldb2, but postfix work

Tags: centos6, sasl

centos6 64 bits:

when i use pop3 for access cyrus-imapd:

```
S: +OK li557-53 Cyrus POP3 v2.3.16-Fedora-RPM-2.3.16-6.el6_2.5 server ready <3176565056.1354071404@li557-53>
C: USER abc@myabc.com
S: +OK Name is a valid mailbox
C: PASS abcabc
S: -ERR [AUTH] Invalid login
C: QUIT
```

and with USER "abc" failed too.

my imapd.conf:

```
configdirectory: /var/lib/imap
partition-default: /var/spool/imap
admins: cyrus
sievedir: /var/lib/imap/sieve
sendmail: /usr/sbin/sendmail
hashimapspool: true
sasl_pwcheck_method: auxprop
sasl_mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN
tls_cert_file: /etc/pki/cyrus-imapd/cyrus-imapd.pem
tls_key_file: /etc/pki/cyrus-imapd/cyrus-imapd.pem
tls_ca_file: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

allowplaintext: true

#defaultdomain: myabc.com
loginrealms: myabc.com
```

sasldblistuser2:

```
abc@myabc.com: userPassword
```

but my postfix is ok with same user.

/etc/sasl2/smtpd.conf

```
pwcheck_method: auxprop
mech_list: plain login
log_level:7
saslauthd_path:/var/run/saslauthd/mux
```

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = localhost
mydomain = myabc.com
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost,$mydomain
local_recipient_maps =
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks_style = subnet
mynetworks = 192.168.0.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8
relay_domains = $mydestination
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
home_mailbox = Maildir/

mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp

debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_security_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
message_size_limit = 15728640
broken_sasl_auth_clients=yes
```

please help.

use imap:

```
username: "abc@myabc.com" can login, but can't get mail
username: "abc" can't login
```

use pop:

```
username: "abc@myabc.com" can login, but repoort: Unable to locate maildrop : Invalid mailbox name
username: "abc", can't login
```

it seems something wrong with cyrus-imapd mailbox.

the mail saved into user/abc
   but fetch mail from user/abc@myabc.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like sasl problem or authentication problem at all. I think you misconfigured cyrus mailboxes. In order to use mailboxes with domain part like `abc@myabc.com` you should specify

```
unixhierarchysep: yes
```

in your imapd.conf.

And then you should create mailboxes like this:

```
cm user/abc@myabc.com
```

I think this will be enough to make IMAP/POP3 work.

UPD: sorry, forgot one more option, you need this also in your imapd.conf:

```
virtdomains: userid
```

Comment: it works.that is great!  Thank you.  it is really hard to figure out from document.